# Python - Comparing lists

Tags: python

I have 3 lists, the first of which is a list of 5 random digits, as shown below:

```
import random

def rollDice():
    dice = []
    for i in range(5):
        dice.append(random.randint(1,6))
    return sorted(dice)

dice = rollDice()
largeStraight = [[1,2,3,4,5] , [2,3,4,5,6]]
smallStraight = [[1,2,3,4] , [2,3,4,5] , [3,4,5,6]]
```

My question is what is the best way to see if dice is equal to either of the nested lists in largeStraight, and secondly whether any of the nested lists in smallStraight are a subset of dice. I am looking for a simple true or false return.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: does order matter here? Or are they really meant to be sets?

Comment: order is not important, added sorted(dice) on the rollDice return to avoid this.

Comment: There is no need to sort here; my solution doesn't require `dice` to be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sets instead of lists:

```
largeStraight = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
smallStraight = [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5} , {3 ,4, 5, 6}]
```

Now you can use set operations:

```
if any(ls.issubset(dice) for ls in largeStraight):
    # a large straight
elif any(ss.issubset(dice) for ss in smallStraight):
    # a small straight
```

You can still turn each list in `largeStraight` and `smallStraight` into a set in the generator expression passed to `any()`, but that'd be a waste of CPU cycles.

Demo:

```
>>> dice = [2, 3, 5, 1, 4]
>>> if any(ls.issubset(dice) for ls in largeStraight):
...     print 'Large!'
... elif any(ss.issubset(dice) for ss in smallStraight):
...     print 'Small!'
... 
Large!
>>> dice = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]
>>> if any(ls.issubset(dice) for ls in largeStraight):
...     print 'Large!'
... elif any(ss.issubset(dice) for ss in smallStraight):
...     print 'Small!'
... 
>>> dice = [2, 3, 6, 4, 1]
>>> if any(ls.issubset(dice) for ls in largeStraight):
...     print 'Large!'
... elif any(ss.issubset(dice) for ss in smallStraight):
...     print 'Small!'
... 
Small!
```

Answer (score 3):

If order is important, for the large straight, you could simply do this:

```
dice in largeStraight
```

and for the small straight, you could do this:

```
any(i in (dice[0:4], dice[1:5]) for i in smallStraight)
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `rollDice` function with this:

```
def rollDice():
    dice = set()
    for i in range(5):
        dice.add(random.randint(1, 6))
    return dice
```

and use sets as suggested in other answers.

You could also replace your current `rollDice` definition with a list comprehension:

```
def rollDice():
    return sorted([random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)])
```

or

```
def rollDice():
    return {random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)}
```

for a set.

However, I'd advise against using sets. It would work in this case, but I presume that this is part of a larger program. Sets can't have duplicate elements, so if you later wanted to check if there was a pair of equal numbers in `dice`, and it was a set, then you would always get a negative response.

Comment: isn't `dice = {}` a dict, not a set? Also, you can just sort if order is important. I like this solution better than using sets.

Comment: I just realized, having `rollDice` return a set is problematic if you're printing the result to the user, as it will eat any repeated rolls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution

```
is_large_straight = any(set(x) & set(dice) == set(x) for x in largeStraight)
is_small_straight = any(set(x) & set(dice) == set(x) for x in smallStraight)
```

I hope it'll help you.